# jquery, don't select children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I am trying to do a dropdown box similar to the "Most Recent" box on Facebook. Basically, have a wrapper that contains both the element(s) that triggers the dropdown, but also the box itself.

The structure I have is this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="text">Click to drop down</div>
    <div class="icon"></div>

    <div class="box" style="display:none">
        foo<br>bar<br>baz
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is essentially a trigger like:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.box').toggle();
});
```

But that also triggers when the box itself is clicked on.

So my question is, how do I trigger the click handler when .dropdown is clicked, but not .dropdown .box? I have tried to combine these, but never succeeded:

```
$('.dropdown not:(.box)')
$('.dropdown').not('.box')
```

I would very much like to not have to create the .box as a sibling to .dropdown, but keep it as a child.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. In your example, `'.dropdown'` will **only** match one element.

Comment: try this `$('.dropdown > div').not('.box')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you wrap the text and icon in a `div` element?

I think it will be easier

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="text">Click to drop down</div>
        <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="box" style="display:none">
        foo<br>bar<br>baz
    </div>
</div>
```

so you can put click handler on the wrapper

```
$('.wrap').click(function(e){
  $('.box').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Very nice! I like this way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

because of event bubbling you need to return false on click of the box:

```
$('.box').click(function(){return false;});

$('.dropdown').click(function() {
    $('.box').toggle();
});
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/t7dxr/

you can read something about bubbling and trying to prevent it [here](http://www.ender.com/2008/04/event-bubbling-in-javascript.html)

Comment: Thanks. I did know why it happened, just would like to avoid the "return false" statement. It's nice if you can contain it in one statement like $('.this :not(.that)).

Comment: @freeall see @Mark's answer for that implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, just check the `e.target`, if it is `.box` dont' `toggle()`

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is(".box")){
        return false;
    }
    $('.box').toggle();
});
```

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/PCTJk/)

This assumes there are no other elements in `.box`  If there is, your best bet would be to adjust your selector to be `.dropdown .text` so you dont have to worry about event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Check which box is being clicked inside the function

```
$('.dropdown').click(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('class') != box )
        $('.box').toggle();
});
```